# ORA-01652: Extend a tablespace in Oracle 12c, no DBA_DATA_FILES table

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, tablespaces

I know that there are other questions about this topic but reading and trying them they cannot solve my problem. Mainly because `select * from DBA_DATA_FILES;` shows me an error when executing, because the table doesn't exist in the database.

I know the different tablespaces using the following query, also looking not standard :

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLESPACES;
```

The ORA error ORA-01652 was thrown when executing a request which should use many temporary space.

The tablespace which have the problem is **R1XQDTM1**. Below the tablespace info : [image: TABLESPACE INFO SCREENSHOT]

The problem is that i don't know the datafiles location for this tablespace to execute the solution request `ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE`

Comment: "no DBA_DATA_FILES table" -- you probably don't have permissions for this _view_. Connect `as sysdba`.

Comment: If you don't have access to `dba_data_files` you most certainly also do not have the privilege to alter the tablespace.

Comment: The existence of a table or view is a potentially sensitive piece of information. For security, the database never says, "that table exists but you can't see it". It simply says it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT/ !!! Now i see you wrote this:

> Mainly because select * from DBA_DATA_FILES; shows me an error when
>   executing, because the table doesn't exist in the database.

In my opinion you just don't have enought rights. You should login as `sysdba`.

Use this select first, you should see location of datafiles (Change the "EXAMPLE" at the end of this command):

```
select file_name, AUTOEXTENSIBLE, round(BYTES/1024/1024,1), round(MAXBYTES/1024/1024,1), INCREMENT_BY, INCREMENT_BY/1024  from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='EXAMPLE';
```

Then add datafile to Tablespace, for example:

```
alter tablespace EXAMPLE add datafile '/oracle/data/EXAMPLE02.dbf' size 100m autoextend on next 100m maxsize unlimited;
```